# Properly show aliased legend items in dc.js (glitchless transitions)

Tags: d3.js, legend, transition, dc.js

My data has a field (let's call it `Kind`) which for internal purposes is a short string (short-form), but which has a mapping to rather verbose strings (long-form), intended for presentation. For example:

```
// Not the real values, but you get the idea...
var kind_map = {'c2a': "Collected Compound Allocations",
                'dee': "Digital Extrapolated Exponents", ...};
```

Among my visualization widgets there is a pie chart that summarizes the data with respect to `Kind`. Since the long-form strings are the ones I intend to display, I have arranged to display them out of the pie slices (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459683/add-legend-to-pie-chart-in-dc-js)). However, as you will notice in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luiseth/MV29N/), during transitions the legend items revert to their original filter values, which are the short-form strings. I want to avoid that, but have been unsuccessful so far. I have tried also modifying the `filterPrinter`, `filterHandler` and others, but the behavior persists.

My code is as follows:

```
cxf = crossfilter(raw_data); //raw_data comes from d3.csv, json, whatever
kind_D = cxf.dimension( function(d) { return d.Kind; } );
kind_G = kind_D.group().reduceSum( function(d) { return d.Value; });

kind_chart = dc.pieChart('#kind-chart');
kind_chart.width(a_width)
          .height(a_height)
          .radius(a_radius)
          .dimension(kind_D)
          .group(kind_G)
          .legend( dc.legend().x(this.groups_base_dim).y(50).gap(10) );

// Expand the group's legend with verbose group names from the JSON config
var kind_name_render = function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll(".dc-legend-item text")
             .html( function (d, i) {
                  return kind_map[d.name]; 
              });
    }
kind_chart.on("postRedraw", kind_name_render);
kind_chart.on("postRender", kind_name_render);
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that at pre-render, the legend does not exist? Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MV29N/2/). The pre-render event is fired but the selection is not able to select anything (check the console messages), regardless whether there is a transition or not. At post-render, however, the event is fired and the selection is successful. Un-comment the post-render event and you can see that in action (console messages).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I gave a look at the code of `dc.legend` and it appears necessary to modify a `_legend.render` function, if I remember correctly. Not good news...

Comment: A workaround to this is to define the `dimension` with the mapped values: `kind_D = cfx.dimension( function(d) { return kind_map[d.Kind]; })` (this makes the `kind_name_render` function unnecessary). However I fear this would increase memory usage and degrade performance, as the long strings would be used for comparisons in all filtering/grouping operations. Is my fear founded?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the new [data function](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#datacallback) in 2.0 to apply a transform to the keys returned by the group.